# WPML Not showing ACF Fields from custom page templates unless the permalink is changed to english

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

I have a site that uses Advanced Custom Fields plugin to create custom page templates. I am trying to use WPML plugin to translate it but it doesn't show my custom fields unless I change the permalink to match the english version. Does anyone know a workaround for this or a better way to set up my custom pages?

For reference this is the template structure:

website.com/custom-page - uses the page template: page-custom-page.php

The fields in ACF are set to conditionally show only on their respective pages: Show this field group if *page* is equal to *custom page*.

And the ACF code for the fields is located inside the page-custom-page.php template.

I have tried changing the permalinks manually to English although this is not a desirable solution.

I was thinking I may have to put the custom fields in the default page.php with conditionals around it but I would prefer to keep my template files separate if possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.